# Jquery show hide div, save state in cookie

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I know is too much to ask but after hours of searching i just cant find a thing...

I barely know Jscript, and i tried many script i found, and i cant get any of them to work. I deffinetly think i dont know how to implement the jscript codes that i found online.

So can anyone please for the love of god help me.

I got the next setup for divs

```
<div id="container">
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

I need a jscript that uses the cookie plugin to check if theres a cookie named "test"
if not to create one with the length of 2days. And the button changes the cookies value to visible or hidden. If anyone can help me out with this i would be eternally gratefull because i just simply cant solve this with the knowledge that i have or jquery...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the examples at
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
and
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

```
function checkCookie() {
    var c = getCookie("test");
    if (c != "") {
        document.getElementById("button").style.visibility=c;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button").style.visibility="visible";
        setCookie("test", "hidden", 2);
    }
}
```